# When did UDP hole punching become off-topic on Server Fault?

Tags: discussion

Well, I was trying to solve a problem that I'm having with UDP hole punching, and my question was closed for being off topic: https://serverfault.com/questions/476877/how-to-bypass-nat-with-pwnat-for-remote-desktop

I have FAQ of this site open here, and it clearly states that questions about networking, routing, firewalls are permitted.

There were 5 downvotes, and only two comments: one complaining about me getting kicked out of university, and one was complaining about me telling my school's IT team is retard. (I gave them appropriate answers after the question of closed under the comments) Can anyone tell me why my question was off-topic, and can anyone tell me why on earth people would think I'm doing something that I shouldn't be doing in my situation (see question)?

Thanks,

Can.

Comment: What you call retardness from your Campus IT team, I call due diligence for not allowing AND helping you to get around network security and transgress your University's usage agreement.

Comment: if you think their network is super secure and my request would be a security breach, you honestly should come and see how awful and insecure most of their network is. i am calling them retards for a reason, not because i'm angry or anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is off topic because you are not working in a professional environment, but in a home environment (the dorm). As the FAQ states, **anything in a home setting** is off topic here. The reason for this is that as the professionals who run such networks, the advice we may give would be wholly inappropriate for a home setting where you don't have control of the upstream network and would be unable to implement the advice.

That said, your question might work on our sister site [Super User](https://superuser.com/) which accepts home-networking questions.

You can also send your campus IT department to us if they express any interest in improving their network....

Answer (score 10):

Here, I've highlighted a few things in the FAQ to help you out. :/

[image]

Comment: ok, I thought it was appropriate to ask network-related issues here without being an IT manager, that's my mistake, but I have no idea why you've highlighted the second part.

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu  Because you're asking for help circumventing security or policy (your university's NAT scheme), and your UDP hole idea could be seen as hacking and/or system misuse.  If one of my users tried something like that on my network, they'd have my boot so far up their ass they'd be able to feel it in the back of their throat.

Comment: well it "could" be seen as a misuse if not analyzed correctly. but the whole intention is to be able to connect to my own PC which is behind a NAT. i'm not into any malicious act. i would do it at my home network, and I'm actually living there, and I need a way to access my PC. in addition, lots of legitimate programs and games already utilize this, so from that perspective, using any of these programs would also be considered misuse. i don't remember signing any contract regarding these aspects of "misuse". i don't think anyone should sue someone without malicious intent for udp punching.

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu You really don't need to convince me; I could only tolerate one quarter of living in dorms when I was in school.  But even if we accept that you're completely right, you're still trying to circumvent policy (which is misuse of the network), still in a home setting, and still not functioning in a professional capacity, so the question's off topic.